# How to edit the regions already being monitored by CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, geofencing, region-monitoring, clcircularregion

Is there any way to edit a `CLCircularRegion` in the NSSet returned by [monitoredRegions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/monitoredRegions) property of `CLLocationManager` object?

I want to do something like:

```
NSSet *monitoredRegionsSet = self.locationManager.monitoredRegions;
for (CLCircularRegion *region in monitoredRegionsSet)
{
    //Change radius of every region in monitoredRegionsSet
}
```

Comment: You will have to stop monitoring the existing region and monitor the modified region

Comment: means i have to create a new region right? dat means i cannot edit the existing region?

Comment: That's right.  You can easily make a new region using the details of the existing region (with whatever modifications are required), stop monitoring the old region and start monitoring the new one